# Ember.js Guide's .observes() sync example not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, observer-pattern, observers

I am working through the Ember Guides and am [reading about observers](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/observers/). They note that

> Observers in Ember are currently synchronous. This means that they will fire as soon as one of the properties they observe changes.

And give the example that

```
Person.reopen({
  lastNameChanged: function() {
    // The observer depends on lastName and so does fullName. Because observers
    // are synchronous, when this function is called the value of fullName is
    // not updated yet so this will log the old value of fullName
    console.log(this.get('fullName'));
  }.observes('lastName')
});
```

Yet when I [try out this code](http://jsbin.com/ludavuluwe/1/edit?js,console) it returns the *new* 'fullName'.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling *this.get('fullName')* in your observer, which triggers the *fullName* computed property to fire and update the value.

From [Ember doc](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_computed-properties-in-action):

`Whenever you access the fullName property, this function gets called, and it returns the value of the function, which simply calls firstName + lastName.`

Comment: If that's true, why do the guides say this will "log the old value of fullName"? If their example will always be up-to-date, what is one that wouldn't be?